# Looking for EPS slideshow software

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, repository, eps

I hope this is not a doubled question, but I haven't been able to find anything using the search.

I produce lots of eps files containing histograms, but the viewer I am using at the moment let me open one file per window, so I was looking for a software able to scroll through files just like a common jpg slideshow program.

Do you happen to know whether something like this exists in the Ubuntu repository?
Cheers,
Matteo